# Finding all the Combination to sum set of coins to a certain number

Tags: algorithm

I have given an array and I have to find the targeted sum.
For Example:

```
A[] ={1,2,3};
 S = 5;
```

Total Combination = {1,1,1,1,1} , {2,3} ,{3,2} . {1,1,3} , {1,3,1} , {3,1,1} and other possible pair

I know it sounds like `coin change problem`, **But** the problem is how to find the Combination i.e `{2,3} and {3,2}` are 2 different solutions.

Comment: What about {1,1,3}, should it be counted once or twice?

Comment: 3 thrice {1,1,3} {1,3,1} {3,1,1}

Comment: so you need all permutations?how ever in your case there are all 363 permutations

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha No, he wants all combinations that sums to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original coin change problem, you "choose" an arbitrary coin - and "guess" if it is or is not in the solution, this is done because the order is not important.

Here, you will have to iterate all possibilities for "which coin is first", until you are done:

```
D(0) = 1
D(x) = 0 | x < 0
D(x) = sum { D(x-coins[0]) , D(x-coins[1]), ..., D(x-coins[n-1] }
```

Note that for each step, you are giving all possibilities for the choosing the next coin, and moving on. At the end, you sum up all the solutions, for all possibilities to place each coin at the head of the solution.

Complexity of this solution using [DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is `O(n*S)`, where `n` is the number of coins and `S` is the desired sum.

Matlab code (wrote it in imperative style, this is my current open IDE, sorry it's matlab and not more common language like java or C)

```
function [ n ] = make_change( coins, x )
    D = zeros(x,1);
    for k = 1:x
        for t = 1:length(coins)
            curr = k-coins(t);
            if curr>0
                D(k) = D(k) + D(curr);
            elseif curr == 0
                D(k) = D(k) + 1;
            end
        end
    end
    n = D(x);
end
```

Invoking will yield:

```
>> make_change([1,2,3],5)

ans =

    13
```

Which is correct, since all possibilities are [1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2]*4, [1,1,3]*3,[1,2,2]*3,[2,3]*2 = 13

Comment: Will the downvoter please comment why in his opinion the solution is not helpful?

Comment: where it is making permutation could you explain that step

Comment: @starter I don't understand your question, please rephrase

Comment: How it is calculating [1,1,1,2]*4 i.e. all four combination plz explain that

Comment: @starter Because you sum all possibilities to choose each element as the first one. When you choose to place 1 as the first element you get `[1,_,_,_]`, in `D(x-coins[0])`. As the recursion goes, it will become among others `[1,1,1,2]`. But if you chose D(x-coins[1]), you choose the first element as 2, and you will get `[2,_,_,_]`, which in turn will also develop `[2,1,1,1]`

Comment: you change your code ? would provide a code in java or c

Comment: @starter I changed the code to make it the DP solution (and not brute force). I believe it is pretty easy to translate it to java code, but I am not sure I'll be able to do so until much later

Comment: @starter I did, the step is go through every element and ask it "can you be first?" Then, recursively invoke on the reminder after using this coin. The DP is only building the array from first to last in order to improve performance.